# Receiving API calls in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to run a python program that listens to calls from other another python program. I tried it through the HTTP protocol, but it's very slow when heavily used. Is it possible to listen to memory entries that another python program writes? Or another solution?
Sending and retrieving calls happens on the same machine.

Like I set up a while loop that never ends and every time looks into a file and reads it.

I guess database software like Google's LevelDB and MongoDB use the same method.

Edit:
There can be several calls at once and the script is running all the time.

Comment: "listens to calls" is too vague to give an answer.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to fix this.

Comment: Have a look at Twisted Python for a suite of communication protocols.

Comment: This question is still too vague.  Are the two processes running on the same machine?  Is one of them launching the other one?  Should the server run all the time and wait for incoming connections?  Can there be more than one client at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a super-vague question, but if you need two processes to talk to one another, maybe you can use [sockets](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html)?  You can send pickled objects through sockets or any other communication method you care to name, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are "the calls" going to be issued from the same machine?

Named pipes may be an option http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2005-March/312152.html

UPD: sockets mentioned in other answer look like more appropriate way to accomplish it

Comment: Everything is on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the most excellent Pyro which gives you remote object calling in python:

http://irmen.home.xs4all.nl/pyro/

Go straight to the simple example, which includes a server (greeting.py) which hangs around waiting for a client (client.py) to send it a message:

http://packages.python.org/Pyro4/intro.html#simple-example